# How to specify end of input in a batch file

Tags: c, windows, operating-system, batch-file, eof

I have a program x.exe it waits for an input from user and reads till end of file. I want to call it from a batch file.

```
x.exe My Text Goes Here and goes and goes and goes and how to say it ends?
```

When I run it, it seems as though x.exe is running, it has already consumed the string I gave it, but it is still pending for more input. How do I specify the EOF character in a batch file?

When I run it from console, I press Ctrl+Z to specify eof. How do I do the same with a bat file?
Thanks.

Comment: In the commandline you have written, `x.exe` is not reading from any file. It might be reading the commandline arguments, but after that it will just wait untill stdin closes. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Peter: @Jon's answer explains everything, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "My Text Goes Here and goes and goes and goes and how to say it ends?" | x.exe
```

The way you're doing it now doesn't actually send the text to your program as input, it passes them as command line arguments (the array of strings that is passed to your main function - it is `char* argv[]` that is `argc` elements long).

Use echo to print it to standard output, and then use the pipe to connect the standard output of echo to the standard input of your program.

Comment: And if x.exe has command-line arguments like -a, does it go like echo "Hello" | x.exe -a ?